Arduino fails to upload Elegoo Uno R3 (resp=0x73)
I have an issue uploading the program to Elegoo UNO R3. Here is what I have tried:

I tested 2 Elegoo UNO R3 boards, but both Elegoo Uno R3 do not work. Arduino IDE found the board and stated the board was connected, but it failed to upload the program.
I've uploaded the same program to Arduino UNO R3 board and Elegoo Mega2560 R3 board. They are working fine
I removed and reinstalled the driver, but it does not work
I reinstalled the Arduino software version 2.3.2, but it did not improve the situation.

What else would I try? Here is the error code:
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x73


An official UNO R3 and Elegoo R3 (using AVR transceiver) are indistinguishable from the perspective of the computer/avrdude/ide. They use the same transceiver, same bootloader, same VID:PID, etc. If these boards are behaving differently one is broken or more likely information is missing or from the question or incorrect. Provide more information. Pictures of what you actually have, entire verbose avrdude output, links to what actually bought, etc. Barring something really subtle (e.g. power issues) anything causing "not in sync" would affect both of these boards in exactly the same way.

Do you have the choice between different (versions of) bootloaders? Did you try different ones?

A bad cable maybe?

I guess they are without a bootloader. burn the bootloader.
